# Android kotlin declare a function in an external class that can be used multiple times but needs a context

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, companion-object

I have the following function `pinAppWidget` which I am using in `MainActivity` but I would need to be able to use it also in `ConfigurableWidgetConfigureActivity` to not have a duplicate of the function I would like to create a class that contains them.

But I'm having some problems.

Code original:

```java
    fun pinAppWidget(text: String?) {
        val urlCode = extractLinks(text)
        if (urlCode != "" && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val mAppWidgetManager = getSystemService(
                AppWidgetManager::class.java
            )

            if (!mAppWidgetManager.isRequestPinAppWidgetSupported) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@MainActivity,
                    "Pin app widget is not supported",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                return
            }

            val myProvider = ComponentName(this@MainActivity, MyWidget::class.java)


            val pinnedWidgetCallbackIntent = Intent(this@MainActivity, MyWidget::class.java)
            val successCallback = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this@MainActivity, 0,
                pinnedWidgetCallbackIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )
            mAppWidgetManager.requestPinAppWidget(myProvider, Bundle(), successCallback)
        }
    }

fun extractLinks(text: String?): String {
        val index = text!!.lastIndexOf("/")
        return text.substring(index + 1)
    }
```

Class function:

```java
import android.app.Activity
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager
import android.content.ComponentName
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast

class function : Activity() {
    fun pinAppWidget(text: String?) {
        val urlCode = extractLinks(text)
        if (urlCode != "" && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val mAppWidgetManager = getSystemService(
                AppWidgetManager::class.java
            )
            if (!mAppWidgetManager.isRequestPinAppWidgetSupported) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@function,
                    "Pin app widget is not supported",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                return
            }

            val myProvider = ComponentName(this@function, MyWidget::class.java)
            val pinnedWidgetCallbackIntent = Intent(this@function, MyWidget::class.java)
            val successCallback = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this@function, 0,
                pinnedWidgetCallbackIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )
            mAppWidgetManager.requestPinAppWidget(myProvider, Bundle(), successCallback)
        }
    }

    fun extractLinks(text: String?): String {
        val index = text!!.lastIndexOf("/")
        return text.substring(index + 1)
    }

}
```

When I call inside the `MainActivity` function I get the following problem:

[image]

How can I do it, can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

you could put **pinAppWidget** method into an object, so you can easy call it in both Activity:

```
class function : Activity() {
    fun pinAppWidget(text: String?){}
}

//convert to
object function {
    fun pinAppWidget(text: String?, activity: Activity){}
}
```

Another way, you could create BaseActivity and put pinAppWidget into it. Then make your MainActivity extend BaseActivity, you can easy call pinAppWidget from here

```
class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   fun pinAppWidget (){}
}

class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {
   //call pinAppWidget()
}
```

Comment: The problem is that class `ConfigurableWidgetConfigureActivity` extends `Activity()` instead `MainActivity` extends `AppCompatActivity()`.

Comment: @Paul it have no different, AppCompatActivity just is a upgrade version of Activity (AppCompatActivity support for older android version)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `Context` object as a parameter to the `pinAppWidget` function in the `function` class.

```kotlin
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager
import android.content.ComponentName
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast

class MyWidgetFunction {
    fun pinAppWidget(context: Context, text: String?) {
        val urlCode = extractLinks(text)
        if (urlCode != "" && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val mAppWidgetManager = context.getSystemService(
                AppWidgetManager::class.java
            )
            // Rest of your code...
        }
    }

    private fun extractLinks(text: String?): String {
        val index = text!!.lastIndexOf("/")
        return text.substring(index + 1)
    }
}
```

Now you can use the `MyWidgetFunction` class in both `MainActivity` and `ConfigurableWidgetConfigureActivity`. When calling the `pinAppWidget` function, make sure to pass the appropriate `Context` object.

In `MainActivity`:

```kotlin
val myWidgetFunction = MyWidgetFunction()
myWidgetFunction.pinAppWidget(this, text)
```

In `ConfigurableWidgetConfigureActivity`:

```kotlin
val myWidgetFunction = MyWidgetFunction()
myWidgetFunction.pinAppWidget(this, text)
```

Note: Make sure to replace `MyWidget` with the actual name of your widget class.

Comment: If I declare the class like this, I get the following problems: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYda6.png

So shouldn't I extend from Activity() or AppCompatActivity()?

Answer (score 0):

This questions covers at least two things: architecture decision and android platform limitations.

From software architecture perspective you could:

- create a common parent class and put this and the rest common logic inside; other activities will extend this class and inherit its behaviour.
- create utility class to encapsulate common logic and instantiate this class within each activity.
- inner classes (aka `object:` in kotlin) could be an alternative to this two options.
- `kotlin` also provide such things as [extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-functions) which could a fourth way to achieve your task.

From Android platform perspective component code should be called only from component (Activity, Service, BroadcastReceiver, ContentProvder). Your function uses component code (`mAppWidgetManager.requestPinAppWidget(...)`) and it would be good to keep it within component and do not put outside. Although, it is still possible to put it into a separate class and pass a `context` to run this code.